# discord roles set gives error when member have booster role

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

im using djs v12 im trying make jail command and im using `<member>.roles.set(["id"])` but when member have booster role its gives Missing Permissions error.
I tried

```
<member>.roles.remove(<member>.roles.cache.filter(x => !x.id == "booster role id"))
await <member>.roles.add("jail role id")
```

when i trying this bot remove all roles from member but its remove jail role to so then i tried

```
<member>.roles.remove(<member>.roles.cache.filter(x => !x.id == "booster role id" || !x.id == "jail role id"))
await <member>.roles.add("jail role id")
```

but still bots take jail role to thats mean member have 0 role
how can i fix that

Comment: Hello. I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking to remove all member's roles except the "booster" and "jail" roles. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah but already i did that as u can see

Comment: Could you clarify the problem then, please?

Comment: bot takes all roles from member then adding jail role but then bot again takes jail role so member have 0 role after that command.

Comment: That is the problem or that is how the command is supposed to work?

Comment: yeah this is a problem

Answer (score 0):

One of the errors is the conditionals  `!x.id == "booster role id"`

This isn't checking if `x.id` doesn't equal boost role id, it checks if the opposite of x.id equals the booster role id, simplifying to:

`false == "string"` which should always be false, so I'm not sure why it removes all the roles, it should remove 0

Another issue is `||` instead of `&&`, with the or operator every role will get removed

but anyways to fix:

```js
const roles = <member>.roles;
roles.remove(roles.cache.filter(x => x.id !== "booster role id" && x.id !== "jail role id"));

if(!roles.cache.has("jail role id")) {
  await roles.add("jail role id");
}
```

But this could be easier with the set method like you stated:

```js
const roles = ["jail role id"];

if(<member>.roles.cache.has("booster role id")) {
  roles[1] = "booster role id";
}

<member>.roles.set(roles);
```